как удалить переход на новую строку в C++builder
не могу удалить переход на новую строку. Сначала нахожу где есть переход, после этого меняю на нужный, и в массив int indexEnter добавляю номер, где нашел переход, но когда я меняю переход на символ, переход всё равно остается, и при попытке удаления с помощью функции erase, удаляет предыдущий символ, то есть 3\n8, он удаляет 3, если поменять место удаления на +1, то удалит 8. Как исправить?
for(size_t i = 0; i < ciphertext.size(); ++i){
    if(ciphertext[i] == '\n')
        {
        char target = '\n';
        b = 0;
        a = 0;
        while(b==0)
        {
            char candidate = static_cast<char>(a);
            if ((candidate ^ generatedKey[i]) == target) {
                ciphertext[i] = candidate;
                b=1;
                indexEnter.push_back(i-1);
            }
            a++;
        }
        }
    }

как я применяю XoR:
int cipherRovno = 0;
      for (size_t i = 0; i < newText.size(); ++i) { //данный цикл меняет символ для того чтобы не было нулевого символа, потому что строка после пропадает
        if(ciphertext[i]==generatedKey[i])
        {
            ciphertext[i] = '*';
            if(cipherRovno == 0)
            {
                ciphertext += "RR";
                ciphertext += to_string(i);
                ciphertext += "M";
                cipherRovno = 1;
            }
            else{
            ciphertext += to_string(i);
            ciphertext += "M";
            }
        }
        else{
        ciphertext[i] ^= generatedKey[i];} // XoR
        procent = static_cast<int>(100.0 * (i + 1) / newText.size());
        Synchronize(&UpdateProgress);

так же перед этим добавляю контрольную сумма с помощью цикла
for(size_t i =0; i<text.size(); i++)
                 {
                    kontrolsumma += (int)text[i];

                 }
                 string sizeSum = to_string(kontrolsumma);
                 text += sizeSum;
                 sizeSum = to_string(sizeSum.size());
                 text += "K1S";
                 text += sizeSum;

После этого обрабатываю конец строки и убираю оттуда всё что было связанно с нулевой строкой, после идет цикл который находится с самом верху, и теперь опять применят XoR и использование earse
a=0;
      if(CR != "")
      {
        int strSize = ciphertext.size();
        for(size_t i = 0; i < strSize; ++i){
        if(indexEnter[a] == i){
            a++;
            i++;
            ciphertext.erase(indexEnter[a],1);
        }
        else
        {
        ciphertext[i] ^= generatedKey[i];
        procent = static_cast<int>(100.0 * (i + 1) / ciphertext.size());
        Synchronize(&UpdateProgress);
        }
      }
    


разделители строк бывают разные

и покажите, как применяете erase

@MBo добавил как полностью всё происходит

Ну т.е. получается, что вы модифицируете вектор (или строку), по которому итерируетесь. Так нельзя. Или копируйте нужное в новый вектор, или обходите с конца.

@MBo можете данный комментарии написать в ответ

@DmitryTurckin Вряд ли это стоит делать - в ответе хорошо бы привести рабочий код, исправляющий проблему. Если совет помог вам разобраться и преодолеть затык, Вы сами можете написать ответ на свой вопрос, это нормально.

получается, что вы модифицируете вектор (или строку), по которому итерируетесь. Так нельзя - на самом деле можно, если делать это правильно - с использованием итераторов. Только понадобится функция remove, а не erase.  А вообще вряд ли кто-то напишет вам подробный ответ, пока вы сами не приведёте минимальный пример, воспроизводящий проблему.

Проблема в том, что при удалении символа из строки размер строки тоже уменьшается. Я бы поместил начальный размер строки в переменную и уже от нее плясал, как-то так:
int strSize = ciphertext.size();
for (int x = 0; x < strSize; ++x)
{...}

И при удалении пробела, то есть двух символов, надо уменьшить переменную strSize-2;.

А почему пробел - это два символа?

Вы правы, опечатался. Я имел в виду не пробел, а перенос строки (то есть "\n").

'\n' - это тоже один символ. Однако, как уже заметил Баракин, разделители строк бывают разные.
